# Make ConEmu close after exiting batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, conemu

I am running a batch file from ConEmu and want it to be as little intrusive as possible.
I have set ConEmu to run minimized and close on exit. But.. after the batch is run, the window stays open and displays

```
ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

Command line is (I already tried variations with and without extra cmd.exe, /c and /k switches):

```
C:\Tools\ConEmuPack.160403a\ConEmu64.exe /Exit /cmd cmd.exe /c C:\Users\test\Desktop\rdp_logout.bat
```

How can ConEmu window automatically close when batch file is done running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all in [docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax). Just add `-cur_console:n` switch at the end.

Comment: It's not working for me. I also changed from latest alpha to stable. But it fails, command window stays open. C:\Tools\ConEmuPack.150813g\ConEmu64.exe /cmd cmd.exe /c C:\Users\test\Desktop\rdp_logout.bat /cur_console:n   Same with /Exit switch I tried first. Maybe it has something to do with it running in admin mode on my machine (UAC disabled)?

Comment: This seems to do the job: C:\Tools\ConEmuPack.150813g\ConEmu64.exe -Min /cmd cmd.exe -new_console:n /c C:\Users\test\Desktop\rdp_logout.bat

Comment: If you use the switch **exactly** as I've suggested, it would be working properly!

Comment: You are correct. I guess I made copy/paste error.